# How do I make a div appear and to disappear on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, time

I am trying to get a div to show on a website for 1 minute and then disappears for 9 minutes and the cycle repeats itself.

I would like to use something such as below, and not use setTimeout().

```
        //gets the current time. 
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 15 ){
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {  
     $(".closed").show();
    $(".open").hide();
}
```

So, the div will show at every 10-minute intervals, so at 00:00, 00:10, 00:20, 00:30, 00:40, 00:50 past each hour for 1 minute, and after this minute the div automatically disappears live on the webpage for 9 minutes.

Would this be possible?

Comment: If you don't use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, what will trigger the code to run again?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Sorry I would like it so you can't just refresh the page to reset the process and to show the div straight away.

I would like it so the div shows once every 10 minutes but based on real-time

Comment: When the page loads, check the current time and calculate the timeout from that.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let timer;


let interval = 3000;
//You can change interval to your desireable MILLISECONDS
let showTime = 500;
//change this for div showing time
//Each div will show for 100 ms

let mainTimer = (60 - (new Date().getMinutes())) * 60000;



$(".divI").hide();
setTimeout(function() {
  let counter = true;
  htmlTimer();

  //runs function every 'interval' MS
  setInterval(function() {
    htmlTimer();
    $(".divII").hide();
    $(".divI").show();
    //hides main content div and shows close div every 'showTime' ms
    setTimeout(function() {
      htmlTimer();
      $(".divII").show();
      $(".divI").hide();
    }, showTime);
  }, interval);

}, mainTimer);




function htmlTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  let count = 0;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    $('.timer').html((count * 200) + 'ms');
  }, 200);
}



let remaingTime = setInterval(function() {

  mainTimer = mainTimer - 200;
  $('.currentTime').html(new Date().toString());

  $('.remainingTime').html('Remaining Time:' + (mainTimer / 60000).toFixed(1) + 'Mins');
}, 200);

setTimeout(function() {
  clearTimeout(remaingTime);
  $('.currentTime').html('');
  $('.remainingTime').html('');
}, mainTimer)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='divI'>Div-1--mainContent</div>
<div class='divII'>Div-2--closeDiv</div>
<br>
<div class='timer'></div>
<div class='currentTime'></div>
<div class='remainingTime'></div>
```

Comment: How does this sync to the :10, :20, :30, etc. minutes after the hour?

Comment: This simply alternates hiding and showing every interval, it doesn't show for 1 minute and hide for the next 9 minutes.

Comment: I have only synced with minutes if you need function to run on specific hours inform

Comment: Thank you, I will use this code, thank you